# ODBC Pervasive Error

Tags: asp.net, odbc, pervasive

I am having the hardest time connecting to this pervasive server for this asp.net application I'm working on.  Right now, I am able to access and view the entire database using my connection string in the server explorer in visual studio however when I actually run it I get an error.  Here is my code:

```
    String myConnectionString = 
        "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};servername=192.168.1.2;dbq=@Live;";
    OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString);
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(myConnectionString, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        reader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (OdbcException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Here is the error I get when it runs:

ERROR [42000] [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax Error: Driver<< ??? >>={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface}

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is only a wild guess as I'm kind of desperate right now.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line :

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(myConnectionString, myConnection);
```

should have your SQL statement in it:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("select * from table", myConnection);
```

rather than the connection string.  When you call the ExecuteReader line, the SQL engine tries to execute the connection string which is not a valid SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would always use the Pervasive ADO.NET Data Provider.  It should be installed with the database engine, but if it is not you can download it here: http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/pages/default.aspx

Lots of examples are available as well on their website.

Also, try changing the connection string to be in the basic form and use a DSN:

```
ServerDSN=DSNData;UID=username;PWD=password;Server=SERVERNAME
```

I haven't had any problems with this setup.